# Is there WebKit for C++ that doesn't use QT?

Tags: c++, webkit

Like the title says I am looking for a WebKit that can be used in a C++ application. I don't want to use QT as you have to pay a lot if you want to create a commercial application. I had a play with WebKit .NET and Gecko but I'd like WebKit for C++ (not Visual C++ as I don't want to be reliant on the .NET framework) without a framework (maybe a form control)?

Thanks Nathan

Comment: theoretically Webkit isn't tied to any particular framework, except OpenGL IIRC. Other than that, there are ports for different frameworks and use whatever you feel is convenient. But what are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: @Aniket I am after a port of WebKit for C++. I am looking to build a viewport for our product and my boss and work mates insist on WebKit as the webapp runs faster in that engine. I have found and tried some for C#, Delphi and C++ (using QT) but QT costs too much. Need an alternative port of WebKit or a way to integrate it in a simple form based application.

Comment: "you have to pay a lot if you want to create a commercial application" - that premise is false, as TomA also answered. There is no problem using Qt commercially as long as you don't modify Qt itself.

Comment: what is your preferred UI toolkit?

Comment: Nathan, this question is essentially asking for shopping recommendations.  Such questions are considered off-topic and non-constructive here, as there cannot be a single correct answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling My apologies, it was just a bit confusing with the licensing of QT and a struggle to find ports :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a commercial Qt license if you link to it dynamically. [It is LGPL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698580/35440)

As long as you use unmodified Qt DLLs and avoid linking it statically directly into the main executable, it is a LGPL compliant way of using the library. You can still bundle and redistribute the DLLs with your installer.

Comment: you cannot still use it for commercial applications

Comment: @TomA Might need a static 'standalone' build as it will be bundled with our app using install shield so could be a problem :/

Comment: @NathanDaly, InstallShield != static link, it's unrelated.

Comment: @Aniket Qt is licensed as LGPL so you're claiming that thousands of extremely popular, commercial products all violate this licensing agreement and everybody just ignores it. Which do you think is more likely, you misunderstanding the license or the first? :)

Comment: @Voo neither :-P Last time I used Qt, it needed a commercial licence to develop with. I googled and stand corrected.

Comment: @Aniket Yes, the Qt licensing changed from GPL to LGPL some time ago (I believe it was around the time Nokia took over).

Answer (score 2):

http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/SuccessfulPortHowTo see this guide to port Webkit to your favorite GUI toolkit. You might need to build Webkit from source for it to work, or work with few of its ports available (see here http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/)